# Taking line intersection of several files

Tags: bash

I see `comm` can do 2 files and `diff3` can do 3 files. I want to do for more files (5ish).

One way:

```
comm -12 file1 file2 >tmp1
comm -12 tmp1 file3 >tmp2
comm -12 tmp2 file4 >tmp3
comm -12 tmp3 file5
```

This process could be turned into a script

```
comm -12 $1 $2 > tmp1
for i in $(seq 3 1 $# 2>/dev/null); do
  comm -12 tmp`expr $i - 2` $(eval echo '$'$i) >tmp`expr $i - 1`
done
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
  cat tmp1
else
  cat tmp`expr $i - 1`
fi
rm tmp*
```

This seems like poorly written code, even to a newbie like me, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite a bit more convoluted than it has to be. Here's another way of doing it.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create some temp files to avoid trashing and deleting tmp* in the directory
tmp=$(mktemp)
result=$(mktemp)

# The intersection of one file is itself
cp "$1" "$result"
shift

# For each additional file, intersect with the intermediate result
for file
do
    comm -12 "$file" "$result"  > "$tmp" &&  mv "$tmp" "$result"
done

cat "$result" && rm "$result"
```

Comment: Nicely done; quibbles: suggest using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead; replacing `mktemp` with `mktemp -t 'XXX'` will make the script work on OS X, too.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Is there any reason you put all of the variable in double quotes? And why do you prefer to use && instead of writing one statement after another?

Comment: @user19192 Using double quotes around variables prevents word splitting and glob expansion (ie prevents filenames with spaces from breaking everything). Also, I originally wrote the code with more error checking, but I removed it to make the logic more apparent. The `&&`s were remnants of that.